# Vue.js - How to pass data to Modal

Tags: html, vue.js

I used vue to populate the item list in my html, and what I want to do, is when the item is clicked, a modal would appear with the data of the clicked item. I'm not using boostrap-vue.

Html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" v-for="items in data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" user="'items'" click="sendInfo(items)">
                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                        <h6>{{items.item_name}}</h6>
                        <div v-for="variant in items.variants">
                            <div v-for="store in variant.stores">
                                <span>{{store.default_price}}</span>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                        <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                            <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                            <h6>{{items}}</h6>
                            <span>{{items}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Vue:

```
window.onload = function () {
  const access_token = "access token here";

  new Vue({
    el: '#item-data',
    data () {
      return {
        data:[]
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      ..... API calll .....
    },
    methonds:{
      sendInfo(items) {
        this.selectedUser = items;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I want to pass the data {{items.item_name}} and {{store.default_price}} to the modal. How do I achieve this?

Comment: is the modal HTML inside a child component?

Comment: The Modal is inside the same div as the html display one

<div id=""item-data>
 
--html display

--modal

</div>

Comment: and is the modal function working atm? at-least the show and hide functionalities?

Comment: also I couldn't see where you declared or got the values for 'items' and 'store'

Comment: Yes, the modal is popping up whenever i click the item, but the content isnt displaying.

Comment: The items and store are from an API response @user9879287

Comment: I hope that access token isn't real

Comment: Yes it isnt, i just randomly created that haha

Comment: I edited the post and removed the access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a variable for the value you want to pass, a method to handle the event:

```
data () {
  return {
    data:[],
    passedData:{item_name:null, default_price:null}
  },
methods:{
   sendInfo(item){
      this.passedData = item
   }
}
```

and on the HTML part where you loop through the items:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" v-for="items in data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" user="'items'" click="sendInfo(items)">
       <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
           <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="latest-product__item__text">
              <h6>{{items.item_name}}</h6>
              <div v-for="variant in items.variants">
                   <div v-for="store in variant.stores">
                        <span>{{store.default_price}}</span>
                   </div>
                   <a href="#" class="latest-product__item" @click="sendInfo({item_name:items.item_name,default_price:store.default_price})">
                   Show Modal 
                   </a>
               </div>
          </div>
 </div>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                        <h6>{{passedData.item_name}}</h6>
                        <span>{{passedData.default_price}}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution earlier but this is the same as what i did.

Answer (score 0):

Use common Vue instance for modal and HTML block to access the same data as. Suppose:

```
<div id='#item-data'>
   <div>
   //basic Html code
   <div>

   <div>
   //modal code
   <div>
<div>
```

then you can access same vue instance variable in your HTML and modal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your modal markup is somewhere inside the element with the ID 'item-data', and so has access to the data in your Vue instance.

The first thing you need to do is declare `selectedUser` as a data property, as  Vue needs to know about it upfront:

```
data () {
  return {
    data:[],
    selectedUser: null,
  }
},
```

Next, you need to change your modal markup slightly, so it's referring to the currently selected item (e.g the heading would be `{{selectedUser.item_name}}` instead of `{{items}}`).

Lastly, the syntax is wrong where you're attaching a click handler to your item row. Instead of `click="sendInfo(items)"` it should be `@click="sendInfo(items)"`.